# Cluster annotations using pheatmap

Tags: r, annotations, pheatmap

So, I am trying to create a pretty heatmap with `pheatmap` function in R.

I want to have coloured bars where the dendrogram stops and the graph starts in order to annotate the different clusters. Like a horizontal thick line running through columns and changes colours when it pass to another cluster. It's pretty common I think. But I can't figure out the 'annotations' in pheatmap. Any ideas?

```
    structure<-matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=100,nrow=100)
    dist_structue<-dist(structure)
    clustering<-hclust(dist)   
    cols2 = colorRampPalette(c('green','white','red'))(20) 
    annotation <- data.frame(Var1 = factor(cutree(clustering, k = 4))    
    heat_chem <- pheatmap(as.matrix(dist_structure),
                 clustering_distance_rows=dist_structure, 
                 cellwidth = 4, cellheight = 4, cluster_rows=T,cluster_cols=T, legend = T,
                 clustering_distance_cols = dist_structure, show_rownames = TRUE,
                 fontsize_row = 5, annotation_row = annotation,
                 show_colnames = FALSE, cutree_cols = 4, cutree_rows=4, 
                 color = cols2,
                 main = 'Heatmap')
```

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example which means showing enough of your data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: i'm thinking that the rownames of `annotation` are not matching the rownames of `as.matrix(dist_structure)`

Comment: Edited, i provided single normal data as numbers don't matter much.

Comment: your code still does not compile

Comment: You are right, I changed the rownames of the annotation data.frame and now it works! Thanks!

Comment: listen, it still does not compile...please delete everything in your R environment and try to run the code

Comment: I did more changes, it couldn't compile as it was missing definitions for cols2 and clustering but now I think it's ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89919/discussion-between-pcantalupo-and-kwnwps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rownames of `annotation` are not matching the rownames of `as.matrix(dist_structure)`